# How to prove that a constant T satisfies the equation $T^2 - 50T - 2400 = 0$ in this question?

Tags: kinematics

A car and a bus are travelling along a straight road towards traffic lights.
The traffic lights change at time $t = 0$, where $t$ is in seconds. At this instant
the car has a speed of $15 ms^{-1}$

. The car then

- decelerates uniformly to rest in $22.5 m$ (as in part (a)),
- waits at the traffic lights for $7$ seconds,
- accelerates uniformly up to $15 ms^{-1}$
- in $5$ seconds, travels at $15 ms^{-1}$ down the road.

When $t = 0$ the car is level with a bus which is travelling at a constant
speed of $20 ms^{-1}$ along a bus lane. The bus is not required to stop at the traffic lights and continues at this speed down the road.

The bus has travelled $240 m$ further than the car at the time that the car again reaches $15 ms^{-1}$

At the instant that the car reaches its constant speed of $15 ms^{-1}$, the bus begins to decelerate uniformly at $0.2 ms^{-2}$.

(iii) It takes T seconds for the car to catch up with the bus after the bus
begins to decelerate. Show that the car must travel $240 + 20T - 0.1T^2$ in this time.
Hence show that $T$ satisfies the equation $T^2 - 50T - 2400 = 0$.

Find the speed of the bus when the car catches up with it.

I have managed to show that the distance that the car has travelled is indeed $240 + 20T - 0.1T^2$, but cannot figure out how to show how it satisfies the last equation and how to find the car's speed. I assume it has to do with finding $v$, but don't know how to go about it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Brian Moehring's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845544/how-to-prove-that-a-constant-t-satisfies-the-equation-t2-50t-2400-0-in/3845573#3845573) tells you how to derive the equation $\ T^2-50T-2400\ $.
- To obtain the bus's speed, you first have to find the actual value of
  $\ T\ $, which is the *positive* solution of this equation.  You can
  then get the speed of the bus from the fact that its original speed
  was $20ms^{-1}$ and it has decelerated uniformly at  $0.2ms^{-2}$ for
  $T$ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You are told the car's speed for the given time is $15$ m/s.  Therefore, in $T$ seconds, it travels a distance of $15T$ m.  Set the two distances equal.